# How to change font size in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this simple JSF table which is use to display data from Database and also to edit data.

```
<table>
    <ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.dcData}">

        <tr>
            <td>Datacenter Type</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.type}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{ud.type}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date Added</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.dateAdded}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.dateAdded}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hour Added</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.hourAdded}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{ud.hourAdded}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date Deployed</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.dateDeployed}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.dateDeployed}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hour Deployed</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.hourDeployed}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{ud.hourDeployed}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>

    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

Now I want to extend the table in this way. When the Boolean flag is true I want to display the text in 12px. When the Boolean flag is false I want to display the text in 20 px. Is this possible in JSF?

Comment: what boolean flag are you referring to? the one used in the `rendered` attributes of the components, I presume?

Comment: yes - `boolean editable`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use an EL expression to set the appropriate CSS style:

```
<table id="idTable"
 style="font-size: #{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable ? '12px' : '20px' }">
```

Comment: Same as above `styleClass="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable ? 'smallFont' : 'bigFont'}"`